# Call an AppleScript ObjC class that is contained in a separate file in the AppDelegate.applescript file

Tags: applescript

I am creating an app using AppleScript ObjC. I have create a separate class file and I trying to call one of the handlers from that class but when I do so I am getting an error about a missing value. Is there anything I need to do to reference the class file before I can call the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two ways vadian mentioned are correct. Here in details:

Make sure your script is wrapped like this:

```
script yourScriptName
property parent:NSObject

on method1
log "hello world"
end

-- more methods

end script
```

Then add a blue cube in IB and set its class to "yourScriptName". Then connect it to a property of your appDelegate.

```
property yourScriptName: missing value
```

to call a method:

```
yourScriptName's method1() -- hello world
```

In a larger project you can build a bridge object so you only have to connect to the bridge and not to every single script

```
script bridge
    property parent: NSObject
    property yourScriptName:missing value
    property otherScript:missing value
    -- more...
end script
```

connect every script to the bridge. then to have access to all scripts only connect to the bridge e.g. in your appDelegate.

Access methods like

```
property bridge:missing value -- connected in IB like before

bridge's yourScriptName's method1() -- hello world
```

Comment: So I have been trying to figure this out for literally months and I have on object set to my class in IB I have a property set to my class and I am still getting the error.

Comment: show what you've done. Step by step with screenshots. We can't help if you're just waving hands saying it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Like in Objective-C `alloc` and `init` the class to create an instance.
2. Use an object (blue cube) in Interface Builder and a property in `AppDelegate`, set the class of the object to the separate class and connect the object to the property.

Comment: Thank you for the information. After creating a new object and setting it to the class I have set the object to a property in AppDelegate.  when I call a handler from that class I am still getting an error about a missing value. missing value doesn’t understand the “handler” message. (error -1708)

Comment: When I try to call the class's method I am getting the error message "unrecognized selector sent to instance" I am not sure what this means